# Finding the limit of the series .

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am dealing with the following:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n i^{\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}}\right)^{\sin^2(x)}$$

What is the limit, it is of the type infinity raised to the power $0$? And I couldn't  find a way to write it as an integral.

Comment: Are you sure about the order of limit? In any event, independent which order of limit you take, it is $\infty$ because

$$ n \le \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{1/\sin(x)^2} \right)^{\sin(x)^2} \le n^{1+\sin(x)^2}$$

Comment: Yes ....first n tends to infinity and then x tends to 0 , as given exactly in the question

Comment: @achillehui Where does your upper bound come from?

Comment: Which upper bound for what.

Comment: @Laertes $k^{1/\sin(x)^2} \le n^{1/\sin(x)^2}$ for all $1 \le k \le n$. so the inner sum is bounded above by $n n^{1/\sin(x)^2}$.

Comment: @achillehui I would really glad if you just post what you've done

Comment: @achillehui But then your lower bound would, by similar argument, be $n^{\sin ^2 x}$ rather than $n$.

Comment: @Laertes $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{1/\sin(x)^2} \ge $ the last term $n^{1/\sin(x)^2}$.

Comment: @Laertes - you need to use math mode. e.g. $\LaTeX$

Comment: @achillehui Gotcha. Not sure how I missed that. Off to bang my head into a wall.